# Data Engineering - infrastructure/services for efficient extraction of data (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, etl, data-extraction

Let's assume the standard data engineering problem:

- every day at 3.00 AM connect to an API
- download data
- store them in a data lake

*Let's say there is a python script that does the API hit and storage, but that is not that important.*

Ideally I would like to have some service that comes alive, runs this script and kills itself... So far, I thought about those possibilities (using AWS services):

1. **(AWS) Lambda** - FaaS, ideal match for the usecase. But there is a problem: bandwith of the function (limited RAM/CPU) and timeout of 5 mins.
2. **(AWS) Lambda + Step Functions + range requests**: fire multiple Lambdas in parallel, each downloading a part of the file. Coordination via Step Functions. It solves the issue of 1) but it feels very complicated.
3. **(AWS EC2) Static VM**: classic approach: I have a VM, I have a python interpreter, I have a cron -> every night I run the script. Or every night, I can trigger a build of new EC2 machine using CloudFormation, run the script and then kill it. Problems: feels very old-school - like there has to be a better way to do it.
4. **(AWS ECS) Docker**: I have very little experience with docker. Probably similar to the VM case, but feels more versatile/controllable. I don't know if there is a good orchestrator for this kind of job and how easy it is (firing docker and killing it)

How I see it:

1. Exactly what I would like to have, but it is not good for downloading big data because of the resource constrains.
2. Complicated workaround for 1)
3. Feels very oldschool, additional devops expenses
4. Don't know a lot about this topic, feels like the current state-of-art

**My question is: *what is the current state-of-art for this kind of job? What services are useful and what are the experiences with them?***

Answer (score 2):

A variation on #3... Launch a Linux Amazon EC2 instance with a User Data script, with *Shutdown Behavior* set to *Terminate*.

The User Data script performs the download and copies the data to Amazon S3. It then executes `sudo shutdown -h` to turn off the instance. (Or, if the script is complex, the User Data script can download a program from an S3 bucket, then execute it.)

Linux EC2 instances are now **charged per-second**, so think of it like a larger version of Lambda that has more disk space and does not have a 5-minute limit.

There is **no need to use CloudFormation** to launch the instance because then you'd just need to delete the CloudFormation stack. Instead, just launch the instance directly with the necessary parameters. You could even create a *Launch Template* with the parameters and then simply launch an instance using the Launch Template.

You could even add a few smarts to the process and launch the instance using **Spot Pricing** (set the bid price to normal On-Demand pricing, since worst case you'll just pay the normal price). If the Spot Instance won't launch due to insufficient spare capacity, then launch an On-Demand instance instead.